# How I get the keyboard frame before the keyboard appears

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button where you get a textfield with a keyboard. At the moment, when I get this textfield, the textfield is in the left corner and the textfield appears. How can I handle this, that the textfield is above my keyboard?

The problem is, that I get the keyboard height after the code in editTextButtonTapped is done. How can I get the height of the keyboard before editTextButtonTapped is called?

// This are my global Variables to create the textfield

```
var myTextField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: 0, height:0))
var firstkeyboardHeight = CGFloat()

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidShow(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification) -> Void {
        if let keyboardRect = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue {
            let keyboardHeight = keyboardRect.height
            firstkeyboardHeight = keyboardHeight
        }

    }

@IBAction func editTextButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        myTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
            self.myTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: self.firstkeyboardHeight, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50.0))
            self.myTextField.backgroundColor = .green
            self.Gestures(addGesture: self.myTextField)
            self.view.addSubview(self.myTextField)

    }
```

Comment: Use IQKeyboard library

Comment: is there a way to do this without library?

Answer (score 1):

There is only this set of notifications:

```
   [ UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification]
```

Only inside can obtain the frame values:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification,
                                                   object: nil,
                                                   queue: .main) { [weak self] notification in
guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else {
return
}
let initialValue = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue,
            let finalValue = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue,
            let durationValue = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber,
            let curveValue = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
        }
```

So, I don't think that there are any possible allowed ways.

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways to do that. In either case I'd avoid recreating the textfield every time.

```
    let myTextField: UITextField = {
        let textfield = UITextField()
        textfield.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textfield.backgroundColor = .green
        textfield.isHidden = true
        return textfield
    }()

    var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(myTextField)

        let bottomConstraint = myTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            myTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            myTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            myTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            bottomConstraint
        ])

        self.bottomConstraint = bottomConstraint

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    }


    @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification) -> Void {
        guard let keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else { return }
        bottomConstraint?.constant = -keyboardFrame.height
    }

    @IBAction func editTextButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        myTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        myTextField.isHidden = false
    }
```

Comment: There you go, I just changed this bit `bottomConstraint?.constant = -keyboardFrame.height`

Comment: I was recreating the textfield every time, because, I want to have several textfields. Every textfield have a gesture, to drag, or rotate them on the view.